# Server 2012 R2 Internet Explorer Security Page slider missing

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

A few months ago we started seeing problems with our 2012 R2 servers in our environment where the slider went missing in Internet Explorer under the Security tab and its automatically set to "Custom"
This is resolved by resetting Internet Explorer but still remains an issue as it happens on several hundreds of servers:
[IE Security tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lp640.png)

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Are you managing IE with Group Policy?

Comment: Yes, but not through Group Policy Preferences, and none of the settings in the Security Page are being managed at all, this occured very recently without any changes to Group Policy
Edit: Also resetted IE to resolve the problem then did a gpupdate /force to reapply all settings, the problem did not reappear